# Difference between Activity log and Audit Log in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics, azure-monitor, azure-log-analytics-workspace

We are devising diagnostic settings for our azure resources, I am confused between both the terms.
As per Documentation:

**activity log**
The Azure Monitor activity log is a platform log in Azure that provides insight into subscription-level events. The activity log includes information like when a resource is modified or a virtual machine is started.

**Audit Logs** - All resource logs that record customer interactions with data or the settings of the service.

Comment: Next time, do not forget to include a link to the documentation you are referring to. Makes it a lot easier to understand what you mean.

Comment: Did you check this [document on audit logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-audit-logs#what-is-it).

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Platform provides [different types of logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/platform-logs-overview). You have the Activity Log:

> Provides insight into the operations on each Azure resource in the subscription from the outside (the management plane) in addition to updates on Service Health events. Use the Activity log to determine the what, who, and when for any write operations (PUT, POST, DELETE) taken on the resources in your subscription. There's a single activity log for each Azure subscription.

and also the Resource Log:

> Provides insight into the operations on each Azure resource in the subscription from the outside (the management plane) in addition to updates on Service Health events. Use the Activity log to determine the what, who, and when for any write operations (`PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE`) taken on the resources in your subscription. There's a single activity log for each Azure subscription.

Also, there is the Azure AD Log

> Contain the history of sign-in activity and audit trail of changes made in Azure AD for a particular tenant.

Parts of the activity log, the resource log and the azure AD log kind are audit logs. Some resources have dedicated log categories for the resource log that indicates entries that are interesting from an auditing perspective. For a complete list see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/resource-logs-categories). For example, an Azure Data Lake Analytics resource has a [specific "Audit" log category](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/resource-logs-categories#microsoftdatalakeanalyticsaccounts).

Summarized you can say that the Activity Log and Resource Log contain many logs and a subset of those are audit logs. They can be used to audit who did what given a specific resource.