# Azure - What are differences between Diagnostic Log vs Activity Log

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

- **Function**: What is difference between diagnostic log and activity log? When to use which?
- **Sources**: DL can be emitted by any kind of IaaS or PaaS resources/sub-resources after we configure from the Azure portal blade. While AL is for all resources as well where some activity is done by user, or app. Is this understanding correct ?
- **Destination store**:  DL can be stored / directed to SA or Event Hub or Log analytics WS. AL are part of Azure Monitor and the storage of the logs are abstracted.
- **Retention**: what is retention of DL and AL? I believe for Activity Log its 90 days.

Comment: See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72797764/difference-between-activity-log-and-audit-log-in-azure/72798632#72798632

Comment: Diagnostic log is not Audit log. @PeterBons

Answer (score 0):

> Function: What is difference between diagnostic log and activity log? When to use which?

#### From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/platform-logs-overview#types-of-platform-logs):

- Resource logs/Diagnostic Logs capture activity to the data access plane while the Activity log is a subscription-level log for the control plane. Resource-level diagnostic logs provide insight into operations that were performed within that resource itself.
- Activity logs provide an insight into the operations performed on each Azure resource in the subscription from the outside, known as the management plane

> Sources: DL can be emitted by any kind of IaaS or PaaS resources/sub-resources after we configure from the Azure portal blade. While AL is for all resources as well where some activity is done by user, or app. Is this understanding correct ?

Yes, the understanding is correct

> Destination store:  DL can be stored / directed to SA or Event Hub or Log analytics WS. AL are part of Azure Monitor and the storage of the logs are abstracted.:

You can also export the activity logs and  store it to storage account or log analytics workspace.

> Retention: what is retention of DL and AL? I believe for Activity Log its 90 days.  :

- For diagnostic logs: 30days
- For Activity logs: 90 days